# Is it possible to have multiple pluck operator (rxjs)

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a problem with my http response. I simply get a response like this:

```
{
    objectArrayList1 : [{...}, {...}, {...}],
    
    
    objectArrayList2 : [{...}, {...}, {...}],

.
.
.

}
```

I can do pluck('objectArrayList1') and pluck('objectArrayList2') separately. But is it possible to apply pluck operator (or operators) at the same time to objectArrayList1 and objectArrayList2? For example in pipe;

```
.pipe(
   pluck('objectArrayList1'),
   *I would like  to work with objectArrayList2 also*
)
```

### Finalization

---

Trying to get something like this:

```
this.http.get<responseType>('https://myUrl/somethingtoask', {
      params:{
        x: '123',
        y: '234',
        ...
      }
    }).pipe(
          pluck('objectArrayList1'),
          *I would like  to work with objectArrayList2 also*
    )
```

How can I reach objectArrayList1 and objectArrayList2 separately (in the same pipe more preferably)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pluck`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.5/src/internal/operators/pluck.ts#L66) operator is used only to get one of the object properties. Instead you could use the [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator with object [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to return multiple properties.

```js
this.http.get<responseType>('https://myUrl/somethingtoask', {
  params:{
    x: '123',
    y: '234',
    ...
  }
}).pipe(
  map(({ objectArrayList1, objectArrayList2 }) => ({ objectArrayList1, objectArrayList2 }))
).subscribe({
  next: (response: any) => {
    // use `response.objectArrayList1` and `response.objectArrayList2`
  },
  error: (error: any) => { }
});
```

Comment: If your question is answered, you can accept the answer with a green check.